# How to vectorize a nested for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

I am mostly concerned with efficiency. I have a very long list of IDs, and I have a second, shorter list of IDs. I want to store the positions of the IDs in the second list that correspond to each ID in the first list (each ID should only appear once in each list). I have written a nested for loop to do this, but since the first list contains over 1000 elements and the second list contains over 80k elements, so the below code takes very long (but works).

```
IDD1 = [0] * leng
IDD2 = [0] * leng
## Match IDs to position in table
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(len(halo_id)):
        if ID1[i] == halo_id[j]:
            IDD1[i] = j
        if ID2[i] == halo_id[j]:
            IDD2[i] = j
```

If it's of any relevance, the IDs originally come from a halotools halo catalog table.

Edit:

The data is literally just a list of integers in both cases. The result I want is a list of integers (indices). ID1 and ID2 are essentially the same thing I just need to operate on both of them the same way. They are a list of integers I have from earlier. halo_id is the same but much longer.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using NumPy? The mention of vectorization sounds like you're supposed to be using NumPy, but you haven't actually mentioned NumPy or any NumPy data structures.

Comment: How will `ID1[i]` ever equal `halo_id[j]` given `ID1` (and `ID2`) is just a list of `0`'s. But it sounds like you just need to turn `halo_id` in to a reverse dictionary.

Comment: could you throw up some example data with maybe 20 elements and the output you want out?

Comment: ID1 and IDD1 are not the same. ID1 is a list of IDs that I have from before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a mapping of ID to position:

```
idmap = {i: e for (e, i) in enumerate(halod_id)}
```

Then iterate over the smaller list and put it through the mapping:

```
idd1 = [idmap[el] for el in id1]
```

This reduces the operation from O(n*m) to O(n+m).